# Should we delete questions marked as duplicates?

Tags: discussion

I came across [this question](https://drones.stackexchange.com/q/584/97) today which reminded me of an answer I posted earlier to [this question](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/582/what-is-a-filtered-power-pad-on-fc/586#586). I flagged the question as a duplicate of the question I answered earlier and explained my rationale in a comment, which resulted in the closure of the question. The OP then deleted their question.

The duplicate asked "How does a Capacitor fix video noise?", which I felt would merit a substantially similar answer to the one I gave to "What is a filtered power pad on flight controller?" in explaining how capacitors can help reduce the voltage ripple which can be at fault for video noise.

When I noticed that the OP had deleted their post, I voted to have it undeleted. In my view, the closed question is a valuable alias for the question I feel it duplicates. I've seen examples like this on Stack Overflow several times where duplicate questions are left to hang around because they can help other search terms get to the answer.

Should we keep questions like these visible on this site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct:

The general Stack Exchange view is that we should keep them as they act as a search engine target for people who may not have found the original question. Additionally, it may drive new attention to the original question which can help with updating (for example if information has changed)

If the new one is really poor quality, then there will be the usual reasons for deleting it, but that shouldn't be because it is a dupe.

Comment: The only exception would be for questions that are exact duplicates, of the sort you'd get by double-clicking the "submit" button.